# How can I add core image filters to OpenTok video?

Tags: ios, swift, image, opentok, tokbox

When I publish a stream on iOS, TokBox uses the default camera.  Is there a way to add live filters to the publisher?

I just want some easy, sample code on how to create a filter and attach it to the opentok publisher object (OTVideoCapture).

Or, if that's not the right way to do it...attaching the filter on the subscriber side works too.

How can this be done easily?

Comment: are you able to achieve it in TokBox for swift?

Comment: Has there been any progress on this issue, especially for Javascript  Opentok?

Answer (score 9):

As I understand you want to apply filters before sending video data and also in real time. There is no easy source code here but I could tell you path.

For real time video filters you could use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework. It has ready to use camera `GPUImageVideoCamera` class. So you need to create class which implements `GPUImageInput` (it is target in terms of GPUImage) which will produce `OTVideoFrame` frame from input and add it to pipeline.

Something like this:

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];

videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;

// filter
filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];

// frame producer for OTVideoCapture
frameProducer = [[FrameProducer alloc] init];
[filter addTarget:frameProducer];

// camera view to show what we record
[filter addTarget:filterView];
```

Also you need custom implementation of `OTVideoCapture` protocol for OpenTok itself. You could use `TBExampleVideoCapture` from [Lets-Build-OTPublisher sample](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples) as a start point. You need to replace camera code with above `GPUImageVideoCamera` camera code to use filters in real time.

Comment: Hi John, what is "FrameProducer"? I can't seem to init it in my code. Do I need to import something?

Comment: `FrameProducer` is a class you need to implement. It must implement `GPUImageInput` and produce frames. As I told before there is no ready to use code here. You need to do this or ask someone to help you.